# from c# how do you get wpf rectangle pixel count?

Tags: c#, wpf, pixel

how do you get a rectangle dimensions defined in wpf xaml in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rectangle has no explicit size set you can get its current dimensions via ActualWidth/Height:

```
<Rectangle Name="rect" />
```

```
double width = rect.ActualWidth;
double height = rect.ActualHeight;
```

If this is not what you are looking for you could try writing more than one sentence.